# Trying to order by date datatable using momentjs

Tags: javascript

I'm new at javascript, i'm trying to sort only by date descending my table,i tried but nothing worked,this is my initial script only for time conversion based on location:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data]").text(function () {
        var utcTime = $(this).attr("data");
        var time = moment.utc(utcTime, 'DD.MM').local().format('DD.MM');
        return time;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please bit more clear what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to sort by date in descending order using momentjs.